# При наведении на ссылку появляется текст, но потом не исчезает

Tags: jquery, анимация, hover, animate

Используя `hover()` а так же `animate()` написал скрип чтобы при наведении на ссылку появлялся `<span>` с текстом. Но столкнулся с проблемой - при отводе мыши `<span>` никуда не исчезает. В чем проблема?

```js
$('.animate-visible-1').hover(function() {
  $('.view-project-hover-1').stop().animate({
    opacity: 1,
    marginTop: "0px",
    marginBottom: "7px"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
span.view-project-hover {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Futura PT';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="animation-element">
  <a class="photo-model animate-visible-1" href="#"><img src="img/stasha-homepage.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <div class="portfolio-preview-text-wrapper">
    <a class="portfolio-preview-category-link" href="#">фото</a>
    <h3><a class="animate-visible-1" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, dolorum.</a></h3>
    <span class="view-project-hover view-project-hover-1">открыть проект</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.animate-visible-1').hover(function() {
    $('.view-project-hover-1').stop().animate({
      opacity: 1,
      marginTop: "0px",
      marginBottom: "7px"
    }, 500);
  },
  function() {
    $('.view-project-hover-1').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0,
      marginTop: "7px",
      marginBottom: "0px"
    }, 500);
  }
);
```

```css
span.view-project-hover {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Futura PT';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="animation-element">
  <a class="photo-model animate-visible-1" href="#"><img src="img/stasha-homepage.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <div class="portfolio-preview-text-wrapper">
    <a class="portfolio-preview-category-link" href="#">фото</a>
    <h3><a class="animate-visible-1" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, dolorum.</a></h3>
    <span class="view-project-hover view-project-hover-1">открыть проект</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем здесь jquery? Можно ведь на чистом css сделать:

```css
span.view-project-hover {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Futura PT';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: .7s;
}

h3:hover + span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<li class="animation-element">
  <a class="photo-model animate-visible-1" href="#"><img src="img/stasha-homepage.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <div class="portfolio-preview-text-wrapper">
    <a class="portfolio-preview-category-link" href="#">фото</a>
    <h3><a class="animate-visible-1" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, dolorum.</a></h3>
    <span class="view-project-hover view-project-hover-1">открыть проект</span>
  </div>
</li>
```